# Is it possible to launch multiple nodes from one python script?

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that `rospy.init_node()` can only be called once per process in the [official documentation on nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown).

I'm trying to write a script that allows for two-way communication (one message publisher and one message subscriber) to interact with a single object. If I have to keep the publisher in one script and the subscriber in another, I'll have a bit of a mess on my hands if I want to interact with the single object.

Is there a simple way of spawning multiple nodes (one talker, one listener, in this case) from one single process?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174849/is-it-possible-to-launch-multiple-nodes-from-one-python-script?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think so.

Roslaunch is what is used to launch multiple nodes. There was a package called [roslaunch_caller](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch_caller) to launch nodes programatically but it is not supported and its recommended not to use.

perhaps a reevaluation of your requirements is in order as it would be much simpler to pass information within a process using traditional programming concepts, rather than using publishers and subscribers via TCP.

**Update**

You can run launch files from python using a cmd line package such as [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module). To change your launch environment you can add arguments to your launch file which can be used as parameters that can be accessed by nodes, and specified by the script.

e.g.

```
ret = sp.call('roslaunch pkg_name launchfile_name.launch arg1:="{}" arg2:={} arg3:="{} {} {} {}" arg4:="{}"'.format(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7), shell=True)
```

using shell=True is required to import the ROS_WORKSPACE setup, but as noted in the subprocess documentation it can be a security hazard.

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-06-24**:
Hmm, that'll demand a near-complete rework of my system. I assume that launching nodes in individual threads wouldn't work either. I'll keep looking into it and see if I can find an answer. Thanks.

**Comment by [JaimeOrellana](https://answers.ros.org/users/30819/jaimeorellana/) on 2017-07-11**:
Is there still no solution to this problem in 2017?